# sudo mysql_secure_installation does not work for Mysql Server 8.0 for Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: kubuntu, mysql

After fresh install of mysql-server-8.0 for Kubuntu 19.10 I've typed mysql_secure_installation from command prompt. And followed the instructions.

Here is output of my process:

```
Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Connecting to MySQL using a blank password.
The 'validate_password' component is installed on the server.
The subsequent steps will run with the existing configuration
of the component.
Please set the password for root here.

New password: 

Re-enter new password: 

Estimated strength of the password: 0 
Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
By default, a MySQL installation has an anonymous user,
allowing anyone to log into MySQL without having to have
a user account created for them. This is intended only for
testing, and to make the installation go a bit smoother.
You should remove them before moving into a production
environment.

Remove anonymous users? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
Success.


Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from
'localhost'. This ensures that someone cannot guess at
the root password from the network.

Disallow root login remotely? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : n

 ... skipping.
By default, MySQL comes with a database named 'test' that
anyone can access. This is also intended only for testing,
and should be removed before moving into a production
environment.


Remove test database and access to it? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
 - Dropping test database...
Success.

 - Removing privileges on test database...
Success.

Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes
made so far will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? (Press y|Y for Yes, any other key for No) : y
Success.

All done!
```

Then

```
da@n53sm:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I could not realize what is wrong?

Here is the output of error log:

```
da@n53sm:~$ tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log 
2020-01-21T07:27:02.077614Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-01-21T07:27:03.414829Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) starting as process 2774
2020-01-21T07:27:03.966655Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-01-21T07:27:03.973831Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-01-21T07:27:04.010871Z 6 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user boot. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1).
2020-01-21T07:27:04.994403Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-01-21T07:27:09.363280Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) starting as process 2939
2020-01-21T07:27:09.847387Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-01-21T07:27:09.872284Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-01-21T07:27:10.013629Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

after restarting mysql the log changes to this:

```
2020-01-21T07:49:41.567105Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1)  (Ubuntu).
2020-01-21T07:49:41.941350Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) starting as process 5006
2020-01-21T07:49:42.479793Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-01-21T07:49:42.501480Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.18-0ubuntu0.19.10.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
2020-01-21T07:49:42.591749Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your output log.

`Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory`

Change the configuration for MySQL for the location to be equal to a folder inside a users folder (i.e. ~/tmp or /root/tmp).

Take note that the shutdown signal is received after this failure. This indicates that the above function was what has caused MySQL to shut down.

Edit: I see MySQL is complaining about the self-signed certificate and the failure to initialise through SSL may be the root cause.

Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342300/problems-setting-up-ssl-connections-for-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04) from StackOverflow

Comment: added edit for answer

Comment: Updated Answer.